# Could anybody tell me what this problem talks about?

Tags: calculus, translation-request, mathematical-russian

I found it in the section on sequence spaces. I don't know Russian.

> Две последовательности $\{a_n\}$ и $\{b_n\}$ называем существенно
>   различными, если $a_n\ne b_n$ для бесконечного множества натуральных
>   чисел. Каждая конечная система существенно различных
>   подпоследовательностей последовательности простых чисел образует
>   линейно независимую систему.

Comment: Your name on this site is weird, considering the nature of your question.

Comment: Is the symbol Φ really correct? From the context, I'd think that notation should be a "not equals" sign, which your copy-paste process has misread as a capital Phi.

Comment: @KCd Thanks, you are right. I have revised the question.

Comment: I am curious:  how is it that you need a translation of *just this part*, and not some whole page or section containing it?

Comment: @KCd Because this question instead of others is a homework.

Comment: This is homework for a math class? It doesn't make any sense as a homework problem, since it looks like two consecutive sentences randomly pulled out of a book.

Comment: @KCd last week's lesson I have learned the definition of "independence of sequences system". That is, two or more sequences $\{a^{(s)}\}$ satisified $k_1a^{(1)}+k_2a^{(2)}+\dots+k_sa^{(s)}=0$ only when the $k_i=0$, $i=1$ to $s$. The class is craming.

Comment: There is no such thing as "independence of sequences system".  You're looking for the term "linearly independent sequences".  Anyway, I strongly recommend you understand what linearly independent vectors are in R^n before you try to come to grips with that concept in a space of sequences (where it's the same idea, but just a fancier setting).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the translation to the best of my understanding:

> Two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are called essentially different if $a_n \not= b_n$ for infinitely many natural numbers. Each finite system of essentially different subsequences of the sequence of prime numbers forms linearly independent system.

Comment: It'd be better to say "essentially different" instead of "significantly different".

Comment: @Sasha Thanks. The $\Phi$ is a typo. You can see the edited post.

Comment: @Sasha Could you give an example for the subsequences?

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the text accordingly.

Comment: Sasha: the text needs updating in two parts, since существенно различная shows up twice.

Comment: @Russianborme: if you can't figure out an example yourself even after seeing the translation into English, I think you should work harder yourself at trying to understand the concepts (i.e., think yourself about how two sequences could have $a_n \not= b_n$ for infinitely many $n$). You did say in a comment to your question that this is homework, after all.